# Bash script executing jar file returns Unable to access jarfile app.jar in ssh

Tags: java, bash, ssh, jar

I have bash script **run.sh** which executes **jar** file:

```
#!/bin/bash

APPNAME=app
JARFILE=app.jar
JAVA_OPTS="-DTitle=$APPNAME -Xmx256m"
ARGS=test

echo "Starting $APPNAME with $ARGS..."
java $JAVA_OPTS -jar $JARFILE $ARGS
```

It works when I execute it on the server

BUT, when I try to execute it using **ssh**

```
ssh host '/path-to-bash-script/run.sh'
```

It returns error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile app.jar
```

Please note, the server is 64-bit Ubuntu

Comment: Is your `run.sh` present on `host` on the path you mentioned in `ssh` command  ?

Comment: Yes, it executes run.sh, I enabled debugging with set -x. It executes java command

Comment: The current working directory might not be what you expect when you run your script through SSH because the current working directory in that case will be your home directory. Have you tried pointing to `app.jar` with a full path to the file instead of using a relative path?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to post the answer. I used dirname $0

Answer (score 0):

One solution which worked for me is to change current directory to the one in which script resides, i.e.:

```
SCRIPTPATH=`dirname $0`
cd $SCRIPTPATH
```

should be placed before

`java $JAVA_OPTS -jar $JARFILE $ARGS`